# What do you do to board a gun boat once you are too powerful?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Just ramming them means they sink. The swiffle cannon makes them sink too. A Scooners/Brigs will be instantly red after one ramming which is convenient.

But the gunboat is too weak.

I like boarding them if I can because that means I can just get diamonds easily.

Comment: Try to trap them so they can't move and then swim unto them.

Comment: well, it's supposedly less time consuming solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gunboats cannot be boarded. Just sink them and loot the cargo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe swimming to them would be the most effective solution, though it would be time consuming and quite dull.